# Absolute imports with rollup

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, rollupjs

I'm trying to get imports like

```
import { startup } from "applicationRoot/renderUI";
```

to work, from anywhere in my application.  I thought the `rollup-plugin-alias` would be a good fit for this.  I tried configuring

```
alias({
  applicationRoot: "applicationRoot/"
})
```

in my plugins array. This came close, but the extension is dropped, so I get the error:

> c:\path\to\applicationRoot\renderUI doesn't exist.

Adding in

```
alias({
  resolve: [".js"],
  applicationRoot: "applicationRoot/"
}),
```

did not change anything.

Comment: why wouldn't the first work in any module?

Comment: @Liam because it's a non-relative import

Comment: right so that lives in your root and you want to not do all the `../` stuff?

Comment: Right, I want to be able to do `import { startup } from "applicationRoot/renderUI";` from any level in my app, and have it work.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use [rollup-plugin-includepaths](https://github.com/dot-build/rollup-plugin-includepaths).

Add this to your Rollup configuration:

```
import includePaths from 'rollup-plugin-includepaths';

export default {
  ...
  plugins: [
    ...
    includePaths({ paths: ["./"] })
  ]
};
```

That will tell Rollup to also resolve imports from the root of your application, so things like

```
import { startup } from "applicationRoot/renderUI";
```

will appropriately find an `applicationRoot` folder where it is.

Comment: Thanks so much! You were close - I edited a small tweak in :)

Comment: thanks for this answer - exactly what I was looking for just now. I'm a bit surprised rollup doesn't support this natively.

Comment: In your answer, will `rollup-plugin-includepaths` include `./folder` if `paths['./']` or do i need to be specific? or add regex to paths parameter?

Answer (score 3):

This is not the answer to the original question, but if you are coming here from search results and are using Typescript, you can set the `compilerOptions.baseUrl` in tsconfig and it will just work.

```
{
  ...
  compilerOptions: {
    ...
    "baseUrl": "./"
  },
}
```

Then if you have a file like `src/lib/util.ts' you can import it:

```
import util from 'src/lib/util'
```